# Problem sending a signal when adding a django child model

Tags: django

I'm facing the problem that I can't track the creation of an object in a child model.
I am using inline in my model. And I want all objects of child model AuthUrl to be output when saving ServerAuth model.
This code works correctly and outputs any changes but when I add a new AuthUrl object I get the error that supposedly the id doesn't exist.
How can this be fixed?

```
class ServerAuth(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="name")
    allow_default = models.BooleanField()



class AuthUrl(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    server_auth = models.ForeignKey(ServerAuth, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auth_urls")


@receiver(post_save, sender=ServerAuth)
@receiver(post_save, sender=AuthUrl) 
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
     auths = AuthUrl.objects.filter(server_auth_id =kwargs.get('instance').id)
     print(auths)
```

admin.py:

```
class AuthUrlInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = AuthUrl
    extra = 0


class ServerAuthAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AuthUrlInline]
    model = ServerAuth
    extra = 0
    fields = ("name", "allow_default")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two signals on the same function. But you can check the sender or the kwargs to determine which signal it is.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ServerAuth)
@receiver(post_save, sender=AuthUrl)
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Sender is")
    print(sender)
    if(isinstance(kwargs.get('instance'), ServerAuth)):
        # Query with instance instead of id
        auths = AuthUrl.objects.filter(server_auth=kwargs.get('instance'))
        print('Server auth post save signal called')
        print('auths are')
        print(auths)
    elif(isinstance(kwargs.get('instance'), AuthUrl)):
        print('Auth url post save signal called')
```

The first few times you got the output because you are querying with the id field instead of the object itself. The id of both models can be same sometimes.

Better querying:

```
auths = AuthUrl.objects.filter(server_auth=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but not really what I wanted.
Here is the output from the console: https://ibb.co/y8L9cqx
Outputs the old queryset before saving.

Comment: That is strange because it is a post_save function instead of pre_save. What is the expected output ? Can you show the code part where you save these objects ?

Comment: I added the file admin.py, so I save this in the admin area simply